# How to make rsync read SRC from STDIN?

Tags: linux, shell, pipe, rsync

I want to dump my MySQL database and make daily backups with `rsync`.

First approach I came up with is something like `mysqldump -ufoo -pbar baz > /var/tmp/baz.sql && rsync /var/tmp/baz.sql /backup/ && rm /var/tmp/baz.sql`.

Then I started to wonder if it is possible not to use the temporary file `/var/tmp/baz.sql`, but instead to pipe the output of `mysqldump` directly to `rsync`.

To be more specific, what I want is quite similar to a command line which we use to update the GPG key for apt in Ubuntu: `gpg --export --armor CE49EC21 | sudo apt-key add -`, where the receiver of the pipe supports this '`-`' argument indicating it'll read from `stdin`. I suppose `rsync` doesn't have a similar argument. But I wanna know if there is a workaround.

Comment: If `/backup/` is a local path, why aren't you writing directly to `/backup/baz.sql`?

Comment: You should implement this with librsync (http://librsync.sourcefrog.net/doc/librsync.html#io-callbacks).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is right, it doesn't work this way. It is because `rsync` is made to transfer complete file trees from `A` to `B`.

Because of the way `rsync` works, it cannot work, because `rsync` calculates several checksums before choosing to transfer a particular file (or parts of it), and doing so in only 2 iterations (ping-pong-steps).

That means a file has to be read several times. That would not work with a (potentially large) SQL dump because it would have to be buffered somehow. And this buffering is up to the user.

Actually storing the file should be the best workaround, especially if it is a file which only gets gradual differences.

Comment: I was setting up a backup system that maintains several copies of backups and deletes obsolete ones with hard-link ability of `rsync`. I was hoping to unify the means for all the files including `sql`s and other types of files. But now I guess it's better to just save the `sql` files directly.

Comment: @leesah That can e.g. be integrated in `rsnapshot` - it can call scripts which generate files. These files can then be included in the sync process.